# Rails + SQL: include join table when no join

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, arel

I have a model, Service, which optionally belongs to a Region. I am trying to write a query on Service that enables me to query services by region title as well as service title.

I have managed to do it with the below query:

```
 Service.includes(:region).joins(:region).order(Region.arel_table[:title])
```

However it **doesn't include** services that don't belong to a region. I want the query to also include those that donnt belong to a region. In the next query, I was closer:

```
 Service.where("region_id is null") + Service.includes(:region).joins(:region).order(Region.arel_table[:title])
```

But...

1. This feels clunky and horrid
2. I need it to return an
   ActiveRecord::Array
3. Bonus: in Arel.

How can I achieve a query that includes records that have associations and those that don't.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not tried this, but you can specify join sql in the joins. so maybe something like:

```
Service.includes(:region).joins("LEFT JOIN regions on services.region_id = regions.id").order(Region.arel_table[:title])
```

Comment: thanks @doon, worked beautifully albeit with a slight tweak. Pluralising the table names:  Service.includes(:region).joins("LEFT JOIN regions on services.region_id = regions.id")

Comment: I pluralized them in the answer as well that is what I get for doing it from my head lol

Comment: Good stuff! Can you link me to any worth while info on left joins?

Comment: Any standard SQL documentation should cover them. Also look at difference between inner and outer joins.  (Not sure on good links I learned SQL 20+ years ago from a book by c j date )